# Can't get android library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have started using android studio for a team project but when I imported the android studio project it gave this error

[This is what it shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROLlM.png)

can someone help me

Comment: Post the error. Currently, the problem you're facing is unclear. Avoid using images and post error in code blocks or block quotes. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) out.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll need to edit your question and put [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that might help you.

First try this one .

[image]

Or you can try this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or this way.

[image]

For both source and target

[image]

Or you can go to your gradle

[image]

and change the `targetSdk` and `minSdk` to something higher than `16`

Comment: You should comment on questions when it's unclear. Currently, I don't think that this can solve the problem.